# Mac script with mv command caused some files to disappear from machine

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, mv

I created a very simple script (terminal command) but for some reason files disappeared after mv. All the files with "mv: rename ........ : No such file or directory" disappeared... but on the other hand other files were moved correctly (although there are no differences between on moves). What did I do wrong?

```
$ ls 2015-10-21_JUNK/*.JPG | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}' | awk -F"." '{print $1}' | awk '{print "mv 2015-10-21/"$1".NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK"}' | sh -x

+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8297.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
mv: rename 2015-10-21/DSC_8297.NEF to 2015-10-21_JUNK/DSC_8297.NEF: No such file or directory
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8298.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
mv: rename 2015-10-21/DSC_8298.NEF to 2015-10-21_JUNK/DSC_8298.NEF: No such file or directory
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8302.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
mv: rename 2015-10-21/DSC_8302.NEF to 2015-10-21_JUNK/DSC_8302.NEF: No such file or directory
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8305.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
mv: rename 2015-10-21/DSC_8305.NEF to 2015-10-21_JUNK/DSC_8305.NEF: No such file or directory
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8307.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8316.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8317.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8322.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8323.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8325.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8330.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8336.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8337.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8338.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8339.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8341.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8343.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8346.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
mv: rename 2015-10-21/DSC_8346.NEF to 2015-10-21_JUNK/DSC_8346.NEF: No such file or directory
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8347.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
mv: rename 2015-10-21/DSC_8347.NEF to 2015-10-21_JUNK/DSC_8347.NEF: No such file or directory
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8353.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
mv: rename 2015-10-21/DSC_8353.NEF to 2015-10-21_JUNK/DSC_8353.NEF: No such file or directory
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8355.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
mv: rename 2015-10-21/DSC_8355.NEF to 2015-10-21_JUNK/DSC_8355.NEF: No such file or directory
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8358.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
+ mv 2015-10-21/DSC_8361.NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
```

Comment: Looks like somewhere along the way you moved (renamed) or removed the destination directory.

Comment: You parsed the output of `ls` which is just about always a bad idea - you should consider using `find ... print0` instead so you can accommodate spaces in filenames.

Comment: Please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much cleaner, more efficient way to accomplish your task.

```
for f in 2015-10-21_JUNK/*.JPG; do
    f=${f##/}     # Strip the leading directory
    f=${f%%.*JPG} # Strip everything after the first .
    mv 2015-10-21/"$f".NEF 2015-10-21_JUNK
done
```